# rails break pasted code into lines and display

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, string

Lets say I have a rails application in which code is pasted into the content text box like the following.

### Pasted Code

```
Person name
Person name
Person name
Person name
```

It is put into the database with the proper new lines after each line according to my server log.

What I want to do is in the show action I want to output this text after removing any blank spaces between names and remove any double names and put them in alphabetical order.

I also want to add an html option tag around them.

I have already written a program in Java to do this using sets. I was wondering how to approach this in rails. I would assume the code to do this would go in the controller.

My second question was in the index action. It shows all the pasted items. How can I only show a snippet of what was actually pasted. Lets say 20 characters long? Thanks!

Comment: Your "I have already written a program" for some reason implies to me that you've written a full Rails application for the sole sake of string manipulation. Please put my heart to rest by telling me that that is not the case :) If it is, you can make your job much, much easier by, heck, just making a static HTML page for your interface and learning a bit of Javascript.

Comment: No no no. Part of this was for experience and practice. You are right that having an html form and have it call a javascript function through the form action that can do this is probably the easiest solution. I was planning on expanding on this concept though using a rails application so it was mainly for practice. The question I am asking is more conceptual rather than "give me the code" which is why I asked for an "approach" : ) You can put your heart to rest (i think). I asked this because it seems foreign/wierd to me to approach it in rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> removing any blank spaces between names

have no idea what 'blank spaces between' means, but I assume you want to remove 'blank lines':

```
lines = code.split(/\n\r?/).reject { |l| l.strip.empty? }
```

> remove any double names

```
lines = lines.uniq # or uniq!
```

> put them in alphabetical order

```
lines = lines.sort # or sort!
```

> add an html option tag around them

```
options_str = lines.map { |l| "<option value='#{l}'>#{l}</option>" }.join('\n') # Do not forget to escape html
```

Or if you want it shorter:

```
code.split(/\n\r?/).reject { |l| l.strip.empty? }.uniq.sort.map do |l|
  "<option value='#{l}'>#{l}</option>"
end.join('\n')
```

That should give you a tip.

The most important thing for you would probably be having [String](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html), [Array](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html) and [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html) documentation in front of you.